# Failed to run connection test on Redshift endpoint in AWS DMS service

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I have created an **Redshift endpoint** in **AWS DMS service**.

When I run the test connection I get the following error message:

```
Error Details: [errType=CALL_SERVER_ERROR, status=0, errMessage=Failed executing command on Replication Server, errDetails=]
```

Both the DMS replication instance and Redshift cluster are at the same region and in the same VPC.

Comment: did you give the DMS IP address access to redshift cluster via the inbound rules on redshift?

Comment: do you mean through VPC?

Comment: yes - the VPC security group you have for redshift must have an inbound rule for port 5439 for the IP address (external) of your replication instance(s)